# rails 4, simple form, select dropdown, include blank or data placeholder if no value selected, else show the selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

i have a form with some user (friendly_id=>user name)

when the form is new, i want to show the data-placeholder else in edit mode show the user selected

here is what i'm trying to do,
if i use only the placeholder, it works in add mode when i don't have @user defined, in edit form it doesn't show the user to be edited in selected mode

if i use only the selected attr, it works in edit mode, i.e. it shows the user selected in dropdown, but in new form, it selects the first user in the drop down, data-placeholder doesn't work

how can i make both the things work together

> <%= f.input_field :user_search_field ,as: :select,
>                         class:'chosen-select',data:{placeholder:'Select user...'}, collection: @userss.map{|a|
>   [a.name,a.friendly_id]},
>                           include_blank:true,
>                           selected:(@user.friendly_id? ? [@user.friendly_id]:'')
>
> ```
>           %>
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to do this easily with using partials. So basically something like this (my example uses simple_form gem):

Create a partial called _form in the user view folder. In this partial put all of the fields to be part of the form. For example:

```
= f.input :first_name
= f.input :last_name
= f.input :user_serch_field, as: :select, class: "chosen-select", collection: @users, value_method: :friendly_id, prompt: 'Select User'
```

Then in your new page put the following as example:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
 = render partial: 'form' locals: {f: f}
 = f.submit
```

In your edit form do the same:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
 = render partial: 'form' locals: {f: f}
 = f.submit
```

You can put the submit button in your partial as well, that's up to you. When the edit form renders the partial it should pull the value of @user and populate the form accordingly. I am assuming that the user is defined in the edit controller action. If i'm off on my answer please provide more details and I'll be glad to help.